# Avoiding SQL injection with a range in the HAVING Clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I properly avoid SQL injection while taking advantage of Rails goodness. For example, this code:

```
Account.group("accounts.id").having("MIN(created_at)": 1.month.ago.all_month).first
```

Raises this exception:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'accounts.MIN(created_at)' in 'having clause'
```

I could do it like this, but then I lose the beauty of the range:

```
Account.group("accounts.id").having("MIN(created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month, 1.month.ago.end_of_month])
```

Comment: This isn't possible. Having uses the same builder under the covers as `.where` so you can use ranges with the hash syntax - `having(foo: 1..100)`. But the problem is that  `MIN(created_at)` is a database function call and not a column or alias. If you use `having("MIN(created_at)" =>1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)` ActiveRecord will give you  `"accounts"."MIN(created_at)" BETWEEN ? AND ?` which of course doesn't work.

Comment: The solution is really to just use a SQL string or Arel to build the query - or avoid having to pass the range in the first place by using the date features available in the DB.

Comment: Or I guess you could use `Account.group("accounts.id").select('*', 'MIN(created_at) AS min_created_at').having(min_created_at: 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month..1.month.ago.end_of_month)`. Not all databases allow you to reference columns from the select clause in having so its a bitty iffy. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases